# listview vertical height is not coming properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

i am working on a App which deals with Contact. i need a custom activity for openening a contact from Contact list which should show all the details.

here, i need to display a label as "mobile"/"work"/"Home" and corresponding numbers.

Expected format:-
[image]

my problem here is, Listview height is not coming properly.i tried below code in xml.

**open_contact.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView_open_contact"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_name_open_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#0d0d0d"
            android:maxLines="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_company_open_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textColor="#403f3f"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView_showAllNumbers"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30pt"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15pt"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:textColor="#0e0e0e"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txtView_label"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15pt"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:textColor="#1d34c9"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/txtView_label_value"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

relevant java code to populate data

**openContactActivity.java**

.........

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
    customAdapOpenContact cAdap;

    if(mob_index > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //listOpenContact s = new listOpenContact("Mobile", number_mob[0]);
        listOpenContact s = new listOpenContact("Mobile");
        listItem.add(s);
        cAdap = new customAdapOpenContact(getBaseContext(), listItem);
        list_showAllNumbers.setAdapter(cAdap);
        while(i < mob_index){
            Log.e("DEBUG: ", "NUMBER: " + number_mob[i]);
            listOpenContact n = new listOpenContact(number_mob[i]);
            listItem.add(n);
            cAdap = new customAdapOpenContact(getApplicationContext(), listItem);
            list_showAllNumbers.setAdapter(cAdap);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

.......

**listOpenContact.java**

```
public class listOpenContact {

    String label;
//    String label_content;
    //Constructor for Single row
    listOpenContact (String label) {
        this.label = label;
        //this.label_content = label_content;
    }
}
```

**customAdapOpenContact.java**

```
public class customAdapOpenContact extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context c;
    private ArrayList<listOpenContact> list;


    customAdapOpenContact(Context context, ArrayList<listOpenContact> list){
        c = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.open_contact, null, false);

        TextView label   = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtView_label);
        TextView label_content = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtView_label_value);

        listOpenContact listOpenContact = list.get(position);
    if(listOpenContact.label == "Mobile" || listOpenContact.label == "Work" || listOpenContact.label == "Home")
        label.setText(listOpenContact.label);
    else
        label_content.setText(listOpenContact.label);

        Log.e("DEBUG: ", "Size: " + listOpenContact.label.length());

        return row;
    }
}
```

output coming as :
[image]

can somebody help me to undrestand what is wrong in my xml? or please suggest new code to get the expected layout (listview part)

Comment: add your complete list item layout.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran : Added full xml code

Comment: could you add your relevant  java code

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran : added java code

Comment: As i see u re using main layout as row item layout. U have 2 options. Either setvisibility of unused items properly or use another row item xml for the listviewShowAllNumbers

Comment: @uguboz : can you pls. give it an answer with example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then main problem is you gave single layout for both your activity and your list item, and you gave dimension to each item and you didnt set default value, so in your adapter it will try to create your view and it will set only the mobile number part so remaing item are empty so its looking like empty space.

To check this try to give some value in your layout it will appear in each item, to achive that you should create 2 seperate layout for your activity and the list item like below

1. Check your root layout of `open_contact` if its not wrap_content change to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
2. You are adding adapter into loop change that like below,

Add adapter to list outside loop

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
    customAdapOpenContact cAdap;

    if(mob_index > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        listOpenContact s = new listOpenContact("Mobile");
        listItem.add(s);

        while(i < mob_index){
            Log.e("DEBUG: ", "NUMBER: " + number_mob[i]);
            listOpenContact n = new listOpenContact(number_mob[i]);
            listItem.add(n);

            i++;
        }
        cAdap = new customAdapOpenContact(getBaseContext(), listItem);
        list_showAllNumbers.setAdapter(cAdap);
    }
}
```

Create new layout list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="#0e0e0e"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/txtView_label"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="#1d34c9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/txtView_label_value"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

give this layout to your adapter

```
View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, false);
```

And change your activity layout like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#ffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView_open_contact"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_name_open_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#0d0d0d"
            android:maxLines="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_company_open_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textColor="#403f3f"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_showAllNumbers"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add you **open_contact.xml**

Comment: it is there in question, I have updated it with root tag height to wrap_content

Comment: are you using a single layout for your activity and list item..?

Comment: yes.. where it should show the contact image, name and below that a listview which has the phone numbers

Comment: @Msn, I explained in my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout structure, your root layout has:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#ffff">
```

Here you are creating the height as `match_parent`. This is why your each item has shown like that. Change the height `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the height of the `TextView` s `android:id="@+id/txtView_name_open_contact"` and `android:id="@+id/txtView_company_open_contact"` to `wrap_content` (You can use `padding_top` and `padding_bottom` for some space around the `textViews` also remove the orientation for the`android:id="@+id/txtView_company_open_contact"` `TextView`

Comment: Just like the accepted answer you needed to create a separate layout for the list items and set the heights of the list view to wrap content.